# USB Wi-Fi адапторы для Ubuntu

Tags: сеть, wifi, железо, ubuntu

Есть список [WirelessCardsSupported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported#By_Manufacturer) для Ubuntu. Интересуют USB, и чтобы габаритами как можно меньше (ну, то есть, чтобы не на проводе, и чтобы не висела такая бандура с антеннами). Вроде получается, что у TP-Link выбор поприличней? Поделитесь впечатлениями, pls, кто с чем имел дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать [**Dlink DWA-140**](http://www.dlink.ru/ru/products/7/756.html) (если вы не относитесь предвзято к продукции под данным брендом).

[image: DWA-140]

- Габариты скромные - 6-7 см. usb свисток
- В эксплуатации 3 штуки под ОС Ubuntu Lucid и 1 c какой-то роутерной системой
- Работает стабильно - поставил и забыл
- Нормально работает в тяжёлых условиях (рядом общага, где в какждой второй комнате по роутеру, в эфире 100500 сетей)

В комплекте симпатичная подставка, можно использовать отдельно как вывод из под стола для флешки

[image: DWA-140]

Comment: Вот [тут](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink#USB) пишут, что с 140 шаманить надо, 140/B2 медленный, а с 140/B3 вообще непонятно что :) У меня лубунта 12.10, получится ли?

Comment: Я не помню какая у нас ревизия, но когда мы их запускали, пришлось ставить вручную дрова с сайта ralink, со стандартными не работало.

Comment: Докладываю :) Вот это заработало сразу же, из коробки, вообще без каких-то дополнительных телодвижений: http://www.dlink.ru/ru/products/2/1261.html (лубунта 12.10)

Answer (score 0):

У меня старый ноут (wifi на борту нет), ОС - Kubuntu13, проблема WiFi была решена приобретением "Сетевой адаптер WiFi ASUS USB-N13 USB"http://www.citilink.ru/catalog/servers_and_net_equipments/net_equipment/netcards/594693/Network manager хорошо его определяет и работает с ним без конфликтов, настроек дополнительных не требовалось, устанавливать драйверов дополнительных не требовалось.дизайн чуть смущает - углы острые (без фасок)

Answer (score 0):

А почему рассматривается ТОЛЬКО USB?
Почему бы не использовать РCMCI, Mini-PCI или ExpressCard (в зависимости от того, какой интерфейс Вас есть). Карты этих стандартов гораздо надежней работают, больше пропускная способность. 
Но это действительно только в сравнении с USB2. Если у Вас на борту USB3 (синие разъемы) - то интереснее прикупить свисток с поддержкой USB3 (нашел пока один: Wi-Fi AC1200 с интерфейсом USB 3.0 TEW-805UB (версия 1.0R)- для сетей стандарта 802.11ac).
Если Вы все-же не болеете "гонкой за новыми гаджетами", порекомендую именно семейство описанных мной карт расширения для Вашего ноута.

Comment: Потому что так хочет моя левая пятка. Если вам хочется поговорить на другие темы и обсудить другие решения - заведите отдельную тему.

Comment: Грубить не стоит, молодой человек. Когда человек не может ответить по-людски, а прибегает к грубости - обычно это говорит о уровне его интеллекта.